# tensorboard() isn't working in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, tensorboard

I've installed tensorflow, as described here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac,
with the "virtualenv" mechanism and also "native pip".

When I want to start tensorboard() function in R, i get the following error as a loop:

[image: error1]

This is my python version:

```
Python 2.7.14rc1 (v2.7.14rc1:c707893f9c, Aug 26 2017, 14:20:52) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Operating System: macOS Sierra Version 10.12.6

Comment: You might consider posting this on the [tensorflow GitHub issues page](https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow/issues).

Comment: Thanks! Here is the link for all who wants to follow this question: https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow/issues/183